# CSS / JavaScript - Styling keywords in text?

Tags: javascript, css

There is some text, and need to change color of some keywords, without using code in text. How can I do that with CSS / JS ?

```
<p>Lorem ipsum RED dolor sit amet, RED consectetur adipiscing elit, RED sed do eiusmod 
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore RED magna aliqua.</p>
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript. They are two completely different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to replace the text `"RED"`, with a span that has a style to color it: `"<span style='color:red'>"`

```js
var e = document.getElementById("text");
var txt = e.innerHTML;
e.innerHTML = txt.replace(new RegExp("RED", "g"),"<span style='color:red'>RED</span>");
```

```html
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum RED dolor sit amet, RED consectetur adipiscing elit, RED sed do eiusmod 
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore RED magna aliqua.</p>
```